# status 401 Unauthorized Auth0 access token Node JS Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, auth0

So I'm trying to get an access token in order to delete a user.

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://dev-owihjaep.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  data: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: 'RGPTciPqTAlJSDoO3zkL4GT1HV3fsptj',
    client_secret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    audience: 'https://dev-owihjaep.auth0.com/api/v2/'
   }
  };
  let accessTokenResponse = await axios.request(options)
```

It worked in localhost but for some reason for my deployed app I'm getting `status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized'` and `data: { error: 'access_denied', error_description: 'Unauthorized' }`. I created client grants for my client, made sure Authorized was switched for my Application in Machine to Machine Applications in Auth0 Management API settings, and made sure Client Credentials was checked for Grant Types for my Application. How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add my .env environment variable(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET) to my Heroku Config Vars.